# For differentiable functions $f,g$, $\nabla f(x)=g(x)x$. Then $f$ is constant on S.

Tags: real-analysis

Problem saying that :

> $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$   is differentiable. Assume
>   that there is a differentiable function
>   $g:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$   such that $\nabla
>  f(x)=g(x)x$  . Show that $f$   is constant on
>   $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:||x||=r\}$   where $r$   is positive constant.

For $x=(x_1,\dots ,x_n)$ and $\nabla f=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}})$, problem says $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}=g(x)x_{i}$. It seems to me that to solve this problem, knowing the relation between norm of gradient and its value is crucial. How can I do?

Notification : This question is edited since it's about same problem and the former one is about just notation.

Comment: g(x) is a scalar.

Comment: For every $x$, $g(x)$ is a scalar. You can rightfully multiply scalars by vectors, in this case it's the scalar $g(x)$ times the vector $x$.

Comment: I see. $g$  is a real-valued.... How could I delete this question or replace it about the way to solve that problem?

Comment: @Darae-Uri I think that's sensible. But that's just my opinion. I think it's even worth it to risk editing this question instead of deleting and asking a new one.

Comment: Hint for your modified question: First show $\nabla \|x\| = \dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$, then use the chain rule with the ansatz $f(x) = \phi(\|x\|)$ for some real-valued function $\phi$ of one variable.

Comment: To add some intuition to what @AndrewD.Hwang said: The assumption says that $\nabla f$ points in the radial direction, which means that $f$ will not change when you move along a sphere centered at the origin. So $f$ should be a function of $\|x\|$ alone.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I show that $\nabla ||x||=\frac{x}{||x||}$, but couldn't understand what you say later. What $\phi$ is? and how could I represent $f$ as a one-variable function?

Comment: @Darae-Uri: In light of your edit, I may have misunderstood your question; I'd thought the aim was to show that given $g$, there exists an $f$, constant on spheres centered at the origin, such that $\nabla f(x) = g(x)\, x$. Alphago's answer seems to be all you need for your actual question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f$ is constant on a sphere $S$ of radius $r$ iff for any curve $c :(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow S$, $f\circ c(t)=C$ for all $t$ iff $ \frac{d}{dt} (f\circ c)(t)=0$

If $c$ is a curve on the sphere so $|c(t)|=r$ Then $$ c'(t)\cdot c(t)=0 $$

Hence \begin{align} \frac{d}{dt} f\circ c(t) &=\nabla f\cdot c' \\
 &= g(c(t))c(t)\cdot c'(t) =0 \end{align}

That is $f$ is constant on the curve.

(And note that gradient of $f$ is radial direction That is hypersurface, which is level surface of $f$, has unit normal of radial direction. Such kind of hypersurface is a sphere.)

Comment: How can r be parametrized by a single variable t?

Comment: I add more explanation

Comment: How do I show the equivalence between f is constant on S and f is constant on such curves?

Comment: Please read again. "for any curve $c$ ..."